# Huffman decoding

Tags: c++, algorithm, huffman-code

Right now I am working on building the structure of the tree for the decoding part. It works when the input is small, but when it is large, the tree will not be built correctly.     How I am encoding my inputs such as `abc` and it works up to `abcdefghijklm` and the encoding is `0001k1l01m01a1b0001c1d01f1e001g1h01i1j` but when I insert `abcdefghijklmn` which the encoding is `0001m1n001a1b01c1d0001f1e01g1h001i1j01k1l` it doesn't work. I get blank values for some nodes. I know it's because my `tempNode` is not traversing correctly, but I do not know. I tried making it a `while( tempNode -> p != NULL )` but that didn't work.

```
For example, a tree like ((c)  (a b)) would be encoded as "01c01a1b"  


Here's the tree in a graphical form:

    / \
   c  /\
     a  b
```

**My method in building the structure of the tree**

```
void HCTree::uncompressBuild(std::queue<char> header) {
char currentChar;
HCNode * uncompressRoot = new HCNode( 0, '\0');
HCNode * tempNode = uncompressRoot;
this -> foreverRoot = uncompressRoot;

while( !header.empty() ) {
  currentChar = header.front();
  header.pop();
  cout<<"Current Character: "<< currentChar<<"\n";
  if( currentChar == '0')
  {

     HCNode * childLeft = new HCNode(0, '\0');
     HCNode * childRight = new HCNode( 0, '\0');
     uncompressRoot -> c0 = childLeft;
     uncompressRoot -> c1 = childRight;
     childLeft -> p = uncompressRoot;
     childRight -> p = uncompressRoot;
     currentChar = header.front();
     header.pop();
     cout<<"Current Character inside 0 is: "<< currentChar<<"\n";
     if( currentChar == '1') {
          currentChar = header.front();
          header.pop();
          cout<<"Current Char inside 0 inside 1: "<<currentChar<<"\n";
          uncompressRoot -> c0 -> symbol = currentChar;
          uncompressRoot = uncompressRoot -> c1;
     }
     else
     {
        tempNode = new HCNode(0, uncompressRoot -> symbol, uncompressRoot -> c0, uncompressRoot -> c1, uncompressRoot -> p);
        uncompressRoot = uncompressRoot -> c0;
        HCNode * childLeft = new HCNode(0, '\0');
        HCNode * childRight = new HCNode( 0, '\0');
        uncompressRoot -> c0 = childLeft;
        uncompressRoot -> c1 = childRight;
        childLeft -> p = uncompressRoot;
        childRight -> p = uncompressRoot;
        currentChar = header.front();
        while( currentChar == '0' )
        {
           header.pop();
           tempNode = new HCNode(0, uncompressRoot -> symbol, uncompressRoot -> c0, uncompressRoot -> c1, uncompressRoot -> p);
           uncompressRoot = uncompressRoot -> c0;
           HCNode * childLeft = new HCNode(0, '\0');
           HCNode * childRight = new HCNode( 0, '\0');
           uncompressRoot -> c0 = childLeft;
           uncompressRoot -> c1 = childRight;
           childLeft -> p = uncompressRoot;
           childRight -> p = uncompressRoot;
           currentChar = header.front();
        }
     }

  }
  else {
     currentChar = header.front();
     cout<<"Current Char inside 1 only: "<<currentChar<<"\n";
     header.pop();
     if( uncompressRoot -> c0 != NULL ) {
        uncompressRoot -> c0 -> symbol = currentChar;
        cout<<"UncompressRoot -> c0 "<<uncompressRoot -> c0 -> symbol<<"\n";
        if ( uncompressRoot -> c1 -> symbol == '\0' ) {
           uncompressRoot = uncompressRoot -> c1;
        }
     }
     else {
        uncompressRoot -> symbol = currentChar;
        cout<<"UncompressRoot -> c1 "<<uncompressRoot -> symbol<<"\n";
        uncompressRoot = tempNode -> c1;
        if( tempNode -> p != NULL ) {
           tempNode = tempNode -> p;
           cout<<"Temp Node "<<tempNode -> p <<"\n";
        }
     }     
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, to understand your encoding: 0 means create a branch, 1 means insert a character? At some point you're going to have to walk up the tree, potentially multiple levels, to find the next place to insert which may potentially be a c1 not a c0: where's the code that does that? Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger? It may help to have a function that dumps the current state of the tree to the console that you can call after every insert.

Comment: @Rup yes I have. Yes you are correct in some cases it does not walk up the tree correctly. Through my analysis, if there is a 0 before a number it's always going to be the left node for example 01a1b. 01a will be the left node (c0) and 1b will be the right node (c1). The else is taking care of that. Yes I've tried stepping through the debugger. It's just some cases I'm not walking too far up the tree, but I don't know what to fix.

Comment: Just curious, why not use the heap (as in heap sort) technique to represent the tree? PS: Looks like I'm 2 months too late any how I think I also got my question wrong.

Comment: Also, I can't help but think that the heap technique and one of infix, prefix or postfix traversals can be of help.